# Avoid if inside loop

Tags: python

I am working in a very single function, but I see something that I feel I can improve, but after thinking about a solution for a while I didn't find it, so maybe you can help me; here is my code:

```
def my_function(metric_id, response_class_id, response_dict):

    response_metrics = db_session.query(ResponseMetric).filter(ResponseMetric.id == metric_id).all()
    response_class = db_session.query(ResponseClass).filter(ResponseClass.response_class_id == response_class_id).first()

    for response_metric in response_metrics:
        if response_class.type == "structured":
            result  = response_dict["entries"][response_metric.name]["classes"][1]
        elif model.model_type == ModelTypeEnum.clf_multiclass.value:
            result = response_dict["entries"][response_class.model_name]["classes"][response_metric.name]
        
        ...
        a lot of things with the result
```

I am getting a list of metrics and then iterating over them for getting a result from a dict, but also I am getting a response class that indicates the way I should access the values in the dict, for that I have the if statement that you can see, but something that I noted is that the if statement does not depend on the items that I am iterating, so I feel that in some way we can avoid the if statement inside the loop and move it before, what do you think.

**Note:**
Also, I think that using something like an eval function inside the loop has a higher computation cost.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. Trying to pull the `if` statement outside the `for` loop will only make the code more difficult to read. A single boolean comparison like this is really inexpensive. There's no reason to try to make this code more "elegant" or whatever. Since the `response_dict` access pattern changes depending on the `response_class.type` there's really not much you can do to clean up the code other than giving `response_dict["entries"]` an alias outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I think having the `if` inside the loop is perfectly fine, but if you really wanted to avoid it (like if the condition you were checking was something more expensive to compute), here's one way you might do that:

```
def my_function(metric_id, response_class_id, response_dict):

    response_metrics = db_session.query(ResponseMetric).filter(ResponseMetric.id == metric_id).all()
    response_class = db_session.query(ResponseClass).filter(ResponseClass.response_class_id == response_class_id).first()

    def structured_response_result(response_metric):
        return response_dict["entries"][response_metric.name]["classes"][1]

    def multiclass_model_result(response_metric):
        return response_dict["entries"][response_class.model_name]["classes"][response_metric.name]

    if response_class.type == "structured":
        result_func = structured_response_result
    elif model.model_type == ModelTypeEnum.clf_multiclass.value:
        result_func = multiclass_model_result
    else:
        return

    for response_metric in response_metrics:
        result = result_func(response_metric)
        
        ...
        a lot of things with the result
```